# onCreate -> scroll to a certain part of the list?

Tags: android

I have an intent that loads a new activity, I also have some extra intent data to get when the new activity is started. Depending on what button is clicked on the first activity, it should scroll to a certain part of the scroll view on the next activity

It would be easiest to have it scroll down enough so that a certain item is at the top and the first thing read (defined by its ID)

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `smoothScrollToPosition` method in ListView:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition(int)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can call to automatically show your list view to the desired position

```
ListView.setSelectionFromTop(index, 0);
```

to find out where to start you must compare the item that you want the list to show at startup from the list and the item that is received from your intent.
if you exactly know the position of a specific item in the listview you can call the method written above directly